# Acces directly to D+ & D- from USB port

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I just want to know if there is a way (in any programming language) that you can acces to data pins (d+ and d-)from USB connection from the computer. 
So, I could to set a voltage of 2 V between them, or for example read the voltage between them too.
Excuse me for my ignorance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. USB uses a complex protocol on those data lines,
and the host (PC) hardware does not allow direct access because of this complexity. You can look at the specs yourself at [usb.org](http://www.usb.org.).